# Disable hover tips when coding in Python - Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am writing a program in Google Colab - Python.
I could not figure out how to disable the annoying function description that covers most of my code, as in the image attached.
It appears when my cursor is amongst the arguments of a function or similar

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Google needs to do something about this - it's so annoying!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable these popups in the settings. Select Settings from the Tools menu. Then, select the editor tab and uncheck 'Automatically trigger code completions'.

[image]

Comment: This turns off code completion along with the suggestion box.  Is there a way to keep code completion but turn off the suggestion box?

Comment: That does not work. It turns off code completions, but not that info box

Answer (score 0):

### Until Google does something about this, here's a workaround for all annoyed developers out there.

Disable it manually by injecting CSS to the page:

1. install an extension that help you change web-pages css content, I'll be using [User CSS](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb)
2. Open a notebook and past the following lines in the extension

```css
.parameter-hints-widget {
  visibility: hidden !important;}
```

[image: Steps]